# Multicolumn GIN indexes in PostgreSQL does not performing index scans on the `preference` jsonb column

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a `preference` column whose type is `JSONB`. And the structure of the JSON looks like below

```
{
    "slotStatus": {
        "reason": "Weather",
        "status": "CANCELLED",
        "statusMeta": "RE"
    },
    "registration": {
        "restriction": "perEvent",
        "maxRegistration": 20
    }
}
```

When I execute `Explain analyze` for the below query, only the `event_id` is index scanned. But the `status` field inside the `preference` column is not getting index scanned. This results in a longer execution time (around 45 to 50 seconds)

**Query 1:**

```
Explain analyze SELECT s.preference, s.data FROM mv_view s WHERE 
    s.event_id= 'event id goes here' AND (
    NOT (s.preference::jsonb -> 'slotStatus' @> '{"status": "CANCELLED"}')
    OR s.preference::jsonb -> 'slotStatus' IS NULL
```

**Updated query:**

```
 EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT s.preference, s.data FROM mv_view s 
    WHERE  s.event_id= 'bc94ec84-a9fe-468a-a805-2124d937c7a0' AND
    ((s.preference::json #>> '{slotStatus,status}') <> 'CANCELLED' or (s.preference::json #>> '{slotStatus,status}') is null)
```

Indexes on this table:

```
create index mv_view_eventid_preference_idx on mv_view  (event_id) where 
    ((preference::json #>> '{slotStatus,status}') <> 'CANCELLED'
    OR 
    (preference::json #>> '{slotStatus,status}') is null);


CREATE INDEX mv_view_eventid_preference_idx1
    ON mv_view USING gin
    (event_id, (preference -> 'slotStatus'))


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX loc_slot_mv_view_slotid_idx
    ON mv_view USING btree
    (id)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Could you assist in refining the query and adding the right index to ensure that both the `event_id` and the `status` field within the `preference` column undergo index scanning

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)

[image]

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, Verbose):

[image]

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, Buffers):
[image]

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, settings):
[image]

Comment: Could you please share the result from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for this statement? And all DDL for the tables and indexes involved. Everything in plain text, as an update of your question. By the way, the `OR` doesn't help

Comment: Reading your update now, 34ms is not that bad for a 100.000 records. What kind of performance do you have in mind?

Comment: @FrankHeikens The execution time it says 34ms, but when i fire the query, it took around 45 to 50 seconds

Comment: Maybe it takes 45 to 50 seconds to move the result from the database to your application or doing something with the result in your application. No index will improve that. Currently the query executes in 33 ~ 39 milliseconds, to find a 100.000 records.

Answer (score 0):

The index is only usable on the thing indexed. The indexed thing is the column "preference", not the expression `prefence::jsonb -> 'slotStatus'`, so the index can't be used.

Furthermore, you are not even using `@>` you are using `NOT ... @>`.  That can't be indexed in any case.

Finally the OR would also prevent the use of the index even if the first two did not.

The first one could be circumvented by changing the query or changing the index, but I don't think you can get around the 2nd one so you are pretty much stuck.

Ignoring the OR and the NOT, the way to get the existing index to work would be to change the query to use @> on the top level:

```
where preference @> '{"slotStatus" : {"status": "CANCELLED"}}'
```

Or to make a new index which would work with the existing query (apart from the existing NOT and OR parts of it):

```
CREATE INDEX mv_view_eventid_preference_idx
ON mv_view using GIN (event_id, (preference->'slotStatus'))
```

But a solution which would work with your current query is a partial index.

```
create index on mv_view  (event_id) where 
    NOT (preference -> 'slotStatus' @> '{"status": "CANCELLED"}') 
    OR 
    preference -> 'slotStatus' IS NULL;
```

But it is not generalizable (to other statuses, for example) and so might lead to the need for one index for every type of query.

Comment: With this partial index it is still performing index scan only on the event id not on the preference column status field. 

I have restructured the query. Is there a way that we can create an index so that it performs index scan on the `event_id` and `status` field of the preference column

And I have updated the query in the question. Please check.

Comment: Edited the question with updated SQL query and the indexes. Please have a look

Comment: @Aishu According to your first plan, the filter only removes one row.  Presumably the planner knows it will remove very few rows, and so using the partial index to avoid that might must not seem worthwhile.  It my hands it does use the partial index anyway, but the estimates are so close that it wouldn't take very much to change that.